# sort array of structure C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, binaryfiles, bubble-sort

I'm trying to sort by name an array of structs that was read in a binary file but it doesn't compile,
here is what i done:

```
struct candidate{
    char inscr[10];
    char name[44];
    int year;
    int position;
    char curse[30];
};
typedef struct candidate Candidate;



Candidate *read_sample_data(const char *filename) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t sz = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    Candidate *aux=(Candidate*)(malloc(sizeof(Candidate)));
    Candidate  *arr = malloc(sz);
    if (arr == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate %zu bytes memory\n", sz);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("%d",sz/sizeof(Candidate));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; fread(&arr[i], sizeof(Candidate), 1, fp) == 1; i++);
    for(i=sz-2;i>=0;i--){  //bubblesort
        int j =0;
        for(j = 0;j<=i;j++){
            if(strcmp( arr[j].inscr, arr[j+1].inscr ) > 0){
                aux=arr[j];
                arr[j]=arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1]=aux;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tested and it reads what i want from the file but i can't sort it.
Ps.: I want to sort it so I can write the sorted array on another binary file.

Comment: If it doesn't compile, you should add the complete error you are receiving to your question.  You should also show a complete self-contained example.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you got your code to compile (did you ignore all the warnings?), but these lines:

```
aux=arr[j];
arr[j] = arr[j+1];
arr[j+1] = aux;
```

Should be:

```
*aux=arr[j];
arr[j] = arr[j+1];
arr[j+1] = *aux;
```

Comment: If this fixes your problem you should mark the question as answered to close it out.